# Append characters after line numbers when using the `listings` package?

Tags: listings, line-numbering

Is it possible to add some characters, like colons, to the line numbers when these are displayed in the `listings` package? There is the `numberstyle` option, but that only seems to affect stuff *before* the line numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the line number placement macro `\lst@PlaceNumber` is set with *every* setting of the key `numbers`. So, below I've updated the `numbers` key to insert a macro `\lst@numbersymbol`, which is now set by a new key `numbersymbol`. For `numbers=left` (`right`), the placement of the symbol is to the right (left) of the line number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@numbersymbol{}
\lst@Key{numbersymbol}{}{\def\lst@numbersymbol{#1}}
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none:\\%
     left:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber\lst@numbersymbol}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right:\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\lst@numbersymbol\thelstnumber}}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersymbol=$\heartsuit$, firstnumber=100]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```